# SharePoint site hierarchy for company intranet - multiple sites or sub-sites with one root?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-deployment

I'm the IT Manager at a mid-size manufacturing company.  We are getting our feet wet with SharePoint - so far we're got one blog in production use> It's the CEO's.

We have use cases for a couple of list-based "applications" with some simple workflow that will be implemented by one of our developers.  We also want to give our users (at least the more tech-savvy ones) the ability to create and work with their own departmental sites.

We're concerned, however, that we might be starting something that could quickly get out of control if it's widely adopted (which would be a good thing).  Since we don't really understand all the architectural trade-offs, we could end up with massive amounts of user data in a structure that bites us down the road.

Our biggest question is whether to have multiple sites for each use vs. a single root site from which everything else descends.  Multiple sites would give us flexibility to make changes or develop new features without creating problems for all the users.  However, multiple sites might be harder to back-up, search, and maintain user profiles/security.  A single massive site seems to reverse the cost/benefits.

I'd appreciate any insight on the one vs. many trade-offs, or links to resources that discuss it.  Links to general SharePoint "enterprise best practices" (sorry) would also be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, multiple sites might be harder
>   to back-up, search, and maintain user
>   profiles/security. A single massive
>   site seems to reverse the
>   cost/benefits.

I would consider this as incorrect. First we need to clarify when we say multiple sites, do we mean multiple site collections or multiple sites - they are two entirely different things.

Now even if they are multiple different site collections, in SQL database, they are just one database, since the database is created as web application level and not site level.

That was regarding backup.

Coming to search and user profiles, again your assumption is wrong. Search and User Profiles are Shared SErvices and they work fine as long as they reside in single Shared Services Provider. Both are farm level services.

A single massive site is (if you really mean site here not site collection) is a complete no-no and a bad design.

I would recommend having multiple site collections (something like Overall department in your company like HR, Finance , IT) and then have subistes under it. This way you have one database in SQL to manage and still you can scale by adding content database to existing web application.

Again here, I assume that you are creating your topology at company level. If this is at some lower level it needs to be refined.

Read some articles on taxonomy and site architecture on Technet before going ahead with any one.

> ```
> Planning worksheets for SharePoint Server 2010
> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262451.aspx
>
> Plan sites and site collections
> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263267.aspx
>
> Sites and site collections overview
> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262410.aspx
>
> Plan site navigation
> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262951.aspx
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It purely depends upon your needs and requirements. even having a deferent web applications for deferent site i can provide you one citation taking backup as advantage. You might have few sites where data does not changes frequently like organizational policies, process documents etc. in this case taking regular backups/search crawling does not make sense(although you can opt for differential backup and incremental crawl but still in a week or fortnightly you have to take full backup). hence i would suggest carefully analyze your requirements and then take a decision. Microsoft has provided a good list of checklist and templates for planning purpose. few of the links are provided in madhur's reply and rest you can google upon.